# Simple dojo Tree with ObjectStore

Tags: performance, dojo

Can someone fix this simple dojo tree? Without ObjectStore it would work, but I need this store for further implementations.

```
myStore = new Observable(myStore);
var dataStore = new dojo.data.ObjectStore({ objectStore: myStore }); // I need this dataStore for further implementations.
var myModel = new dijit.tree.TreeStoreModel({
                    store: dataStore,
                    query: { id: 'world' }
                });
```

Here you find the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zawSX/50/) for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an object store, I believe you need ObjectStoreModel instead of TreeStoreModel:

```
/*var myModel = new TreeStoreModel({
    store: myStore,//dataStore,
    query: { id: 'world' }
});*/

var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
    store: myStore,
    query: { id: 'world' }
});
```

The TreeStoreModel and ForestStoreModel classes are legacy models for dojo.data, while the ObjectStoreModel is for when you use dojo.store.

See if this fiddle works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zawSX/52/

Comment: I came up with the same solution. But for that I don't use var dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: myStore }); to initialize my ObjectStoreModel. Thanks for your help.